# RESTAdapter in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to EmberJs and I don't clearly understand in Ember's Adapter .I just try the ember adapter in my App.Js like that and I got this error ( Assertion failed: You tried to set `adapter` property to an instance of `DS.Adapter`, where it should be a name or a factory ) .  My ember's code in App.js is :

```
//Store
App.Adapter =  DS.RESTAdapter.extend();
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: App.Adapter.create()
});
//Models
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    price: DS.attr('number')
});

// Products Route
 App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: (function() {
      return this.store.find('Product');
  })
});
return App;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you misunderstand the way you setup and configure adapters.

```
//
// Application-wide adapter, everything will use this unless you override it
//

App.ApplicationAdapter =  DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com'
});

//
// Product model, will use ApplicationAdapter
// 

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  name        : DS.attr('string'),
  description : DS.attr('string'),
  price       : DS.attr('number')
});

//
// Invoice model, will use fixtures, so specify a different adapter 
// 

App.InvoiceAdapter =  DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({ /* options */ });

App.Invoice = DS.Model.extend({
  name   : DS.attr('string'),
  amount : DS.attr('number')
});

//    
// Routes, these should work as expected
//

App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('product', params.id);
  }
});

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('product');
  }
});

App.InvoicesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('invoice');
  }
});

return App;
```

Ember will know which models/routes/etc to use based on their names - see http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/ for the details.

Answer (score 1):

Define the store in this way

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: App.Adapter
});
```

Without the create().

Answer (score 1):

The main use of the adapter is to do the serialization and deserailzation of the data according to some conventions like constructing the url to post or get data from and then constructing the actual objects from the response. The Default adapter used by ember data models is the Rest adapter.

see

> http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/
>   for more details

To use a different adapter other than the rest adapter you can specify its name like

`Storm.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      adapter: '_ams',
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();
```

This works for me